# Can tag gold-badge holders take off their golden hat when casting close votes?

Tags: support, review, badges, vote-to-close, dupehammer

It was [my understanding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders) that when a tag gold-badge (TGB) holder casts a close vote for dupes, the question gets closed immediately. It [doesn't matter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243840/gold-badge-duplicate-close-and-reopen-vote-invalidates-existing-votes) in what order a TGB holder casts their vote.

I have gold tag badges only on Sci-fi & Fantasy Stack Exchange, which I mostly refrain from using due to my tendency to avoid the arguments which nearly always occur when one user hammers a question instead of a community consensus via a review (unless I am up for an argument, which is very rare).

But yesterday, on Stack Overflow, [I noticed something different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215529/how-to-upgrade-xcode-to-9-2). The fourth voter there holds a gold badge in the iOS tag. Yet, the question wasn't closed until it got a fifth vote. So that got me thinking: Is it possible for TGB holders to take off their golden hat and vote as a normal user? Or do gold-badge closing privileges vary based on where they are coming for i.e. A review requiring five people to agree, irrelevant to the badges they hold while a direct close vote outside the review queue would instantly close the post?

If they can take off the golden hat, how does one do that?

Comment: TL;DR: no, it is not possible.

Comment: No, you can't. The gold tag badge holder presumably cast a close vote for something other than a duplicate (a gold tag badge holder can't single-handedly close for any reason other than duplicate). The close reason is determined by the votes of the majority - every close voter does not need to use the same close reason.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Cheers. On a side note, I am still curious why wasn't the cited post closed after a TGB holder cast their vote. Should I ask a new question about that or rephrase the current one? It looked like as if they had taken off their golden hat, which is why I phrased it this way (And to see if I could do the same but the dupe answers that)

Comment: @Dukeling Right. `The gold tag badge holder presumably cast a close vote for something other than a duplicate.`, So that might be why It still needed another vote. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the only way I can think of is what Dukeling said.